# Mount NFS - no wait if server not responding

Tags: centos7, mount, nfs

In **Centos7** I mount remote folder with this command:

```
mount -t nfs-o soft,timeo=900,retrans=1,vers=4.1 X.X.X.X:/nfsshare /nfsshare
```

The mount work fine.

I want get an error or a fast timeout if remote *NFS server* not responding, bud not work.
If I try to access to remote file when *NFS Server* in down, I wait permanent without error or timeout.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix with this configuration:

```
mount -t nfs -o soft,nomand,nofail,timeo=1,retrans=1,_netdev,rw X.X.X.X:/nfsshare /nfsshare
```